# virtual machine on ESXI - File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, esxi

Windows server 2012 r2 - I created a virtual machine on ESXI. the machine worked properly till yesterday. Today I can't power on the virtual machine. It gives this error :

> machineFile system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed

Comment: [You encountered data corruption of a required file. Restore the file from your backup.](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/83291)